# How to convert binary to json in flutter using dart

Tags: dart, flutter

How to convert binary to json in flutter using  dart please help me out for this.

```
 _alt((snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync().toString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear from your question what `snapshot.data` is and why you use `readAsBytesSync()`, but a guess is you are looking for:

```
import 'dart:convert';
...

String data = base64.encode(snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync());
```

Comment: 'BASE64' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: It showing this error please help me out .

Comment: Use `base64` instead of `BASE64`

Comment: String data = base64Encode(snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync()); I tried with this code and it is working fine. Thanks for your support.